# Why WriteXml create a new xml file

Tags: xml, wpf, datagrid

I try to use `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` to load/save a xml file in `datagrid`, but the `WriteXml` method just create a new empty file instead of save changes to the old one. For details: [Link][1]

----------------------------------update----------------------------------------

```
    private void RefreshModule()
    {
        ModulesView = new ListCollectionView(sdb.GetModules())
        {
            Filter = obj =>
            {
                var Module = (Module)obj;
                return SelectedProduct != null && SelectedProduct.ModelNumber == Module.ModelNumber;
            }
        };
    }

    private Product selectedProduct;
    public Product SelectedProduct
    {

        get { return selectedProduct; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedProduct != value)
            {
                selectedProduct = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
                RefreshModule();
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save datagrid changes back to xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541693/save-datagrid-changes-back-to-xml-file)

Comment: Don't make duplicates of the same question. In your original question I see no attempt to use `WriteXml`, you probably aren't using it properly.

Comment: Sorry for this, but i really need to solve this problem. I tried to `StoreDbDataSet sdb = new StoreDbDataSet();
 sdb.WriteXml("store.xml");` In a `Button_Click` event, and it  turned out to create  a new empty `store.xml` file.

Comment: How do you set the ModulesView property?

Comment: @mm8 Thanks for your reply, I updated my usage of `ModulesView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SaveDataSet` method of your `StoreDbDataSet` class should take a `DataSet` parameter and serialize this one to the file.

```
public void SaveDataSet(DatatSet ds)
{
    ds.WriteXmlSchema(DatabaseConstructorName);
    ds.WriteXml(DatabaseFileName);
    ds.AcceptChanges();
}
```

But how are you supposed to be able to serialize a `DataSet` if you set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to an `ObservableCollection`?

Return the `DataSet` from your `GetModules` method:

```
public DataSet GetModules()
{
    return StoreDbDataSet.ReadDataSet();
}
```

And bind to the `DataView` of the `DataTable`. Something like this:

```
private DataSet _ds;
private void RefreshModule()
{
    _ds = sdb.GetModules();
    ModulesView = new ListCollectionView(ds.Tables["Modules"].DefaultView)
    {
        Filter = obj =>
        {
            var Module = obj as DataRowView;
            return SelectedProduct != null && SelectedProduct.ModelNumber == Module["ModelNumber"].ToString(); //ModuleNumber is the column name in the DataTable
        }
    };
}

private void Writecfg_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StoreDbDataSet sdb = new StoreDbDataSet();
    sdb.SaveDataSet(_ds);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for replying late. After I tried your code, the `DataTable` **Modules** doesn't populate anything, and with an warning in your code `Possible unintended reference comparison`

Comment: Is the ModelNumber  property of the Product class an int or a string?

Comment: It is a `string` type.

Comment: Thanks for the modify, after trying your latest code, the `sdb.SaveDataSet()` did called but without saving changes to the xml file. By the way, is the `ds` in the method `RefreshModule` and `Writecfg_Button_Click` supposed to `_ds` ?

Comment: Yes. So put a breakpoint in the SaveDataSet method and find out how the DataSet and the tables look like when saving.

Comment: Sorry for being wordy, I tried to monitor the `ds` in the `SaveDataSet` method but could not find the DataSet property changes as the images I updated.

Comment: Expand the Tables node and check what data the DataTable actually contains.

Comment: The `DataTable` and **Table** `Modules` monitor result as above.

Comment: I don't know what kind of answer you are looking for. Please provide a full repo of your issue when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry, I just don't know why this code doesn't work, thanks for your generous help!